# paracol and footnote placing in Latex

Tags: latex

For my current project I need two text lined up in two column. The idea is that one column shows the original language and the second column its translation, neatly lined up line by line. The package paracol does what I want except for one thing: footnote placement.

If one of the columns has a footnote and the other hasn't, the lines of the original and the translation do not stay together. The footnote disrupts the lining up of lines.

This is an example in which you can see that "some other text that should be next to the line in the left column" is not lined up with the lines of the original. All because of the footnote.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn
text with footnote\footnote{the footnote}

and some other text

\switchcolumn
the translation without footnote

some other text that should be next to the line in the left column

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the footnote disrupts the alignment of lines. How to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem by adding the following line after loading the paracol package:

```
\footnotelayout{p}
```

This ensures that footnotes are layed out for the whole page instead of the default of per column.

(Since I also added footmisc with the perpage parameter, I also had to delete the perpage parameter and add this:

```
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\setcounter{footnote}{0}} % resets footnote counter on every page
```

)